# MongoDB: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

Recently I am using mongodb java async driver which is newly released. I am writing some simple test codes, which are:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
    System.out.println("database has been connected!");

    SingleResultCallback<Void> callbackWhenFinished = new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Operation Finished!");
        }
    };

    mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().forEach(new Block<String>() {
        @Override
        public void apply(final String s) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }, callbackWhenFinished);
```

however, the callback function is not called, the console output is:

> April 18, 2015 10:50:27 afternoon
>   com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log message: Cluster created
>   with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE,
>   requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms',
>   maxWaitQueueSize=500}
>   **database has been connected!**       April 18, 2015 10:50:28 afternoon com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log message: **No
>   server chosen by
>   ReadPreferenceServerSelector**{readPreference=primary} from cluster
>   description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE,
>   all=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN,
>   state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out

So you can see there is no callback function called. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is your callback will be called eventually.

For the long answer, lets work through your code:

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();
    System.out.println("database has been connected!");
```

`MongoClient` doesn't block waiting for a connection to MongoDB in the background the internal connection pool is trying to connect.  From your logs I can see you have the default `serverSelectionTimeout` of 30000ms.

Next step you do a `println` which output immediately so "database has been connected!" gets printed regardless.

Finally, you call `listDatabaseNames()` but what's not clear is if any waits for the callback to be called.  If you add a latch then await the response then you will see that the callback is called eg:

```
  System.out.println("======= Start =======");

  MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create();

  final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

  SingleResultCallback<Void> callbackWhenFinished = new SingleResultCallback<Void>() {
      @Override
      public void onResult(final Void result, final Throwable t) {
          System.out.println("Operation Finished!");
          if (t != null) {
              System.out.println("listDatabaseNames() errored: " + t.getMessage());
          }
          latch.countDown();
      }
  };

  mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().forEach(new Block<String>() {
      @Override
      public void apply(final String s) {
          System.out.println(s);
      }
  }, callbackWhenFinished);

  latch.await();

  // close resources
  mongoClient.close();
  System.out.println("======= Finish =======");
```

Now using the latch we `await()` until the callback has been called, now we should see one of two things happen:

1. There is no MongoDB available. 
   It will eventually call the callback and print that there was an error. It will wait until the `serverSelectionTimeout` times out.
2. There is a MongoDB available.
   It will eventually connect, for each database it will apply the `Block` and print out the database name and then finally it will call the callback signalling it has finished.

Comment: Why should I call wait explicitly, shouldn't the program wait until all user thread finished?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should close the MongoClient object every time in a finally clause. For me the same problem occured, and when I closed the connection in the command line I saw that a LOT of connections were open.

Try something like this (I use mongodb 3.0.7 and mongo-java-driver 3.1.0):

```
package com.mkyong.core;

import org.bson.Document;
import org.junit.Test;

import com.mongodb.Block;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.FindIterable;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

/**
 * Unit test for simple App.
 */
public class AppTest {

    @Test
    public void firstTest() throws Exception {
        MongoClient mongoClient = null;
        try {
            mongoClient = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("census");
            FindIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("states").find();
            iterable.forEach(new Block<Document>() {
                @Override
                public void apply(final Document document) {
                    System.out.println(document);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                mongoClient.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
            }
        }
    }

}
```

With this, I could use my connection with no problem.